# wxPython - Screen resolution 3000x2000 and DPI on 200% problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython, screen-resolution

I wrote an Tool with a wxPython GUI. On Full HD and less everything runs fine. A friend of mine tested a bit with my tool and he uses a Microsoft Surface Book laptop with a screen resolution of 3000x2000 and DPI set to 200% on Windows 10.

And he has the problem that everything in my GUI is very small.

I tried to prevent that with this piece of code:

```
import ctypes
try:
    ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(True)
except:
    pass
```

But that didnt help at all. Does anybody have experience with a problem like that? What else could i try?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is already a question similar to this in Stackoverflow. Anyway.

So far I think the only thing you can do is to set the app to use System (Enhanced) in the High DPI scaling override box.

[image]

It does not matter if you do not have a .exe file. You can change the properties of the resulting python app window when you run it as `python myApp.py`.

If the picture is not enough, there are more details in the first question [here](https://www.umsap.nl/faq).